# pleas let me know how to put GEKKO Parameter in Variable

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I want to put GEKKO Parameter 'N' in Varibale 'Y', but i got an error like below one.
I mean that the Parameter 'N' should be changed continuously when the optimization is going on.
Is there any other way that could make a changing N?

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
k = 10
N = m.Param(value=[i+1 for i in range(6)])

Y = m.Array(m.Var, (N, k))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(k):
        Y[i, j].value = 0
        Y[i, j].lower = 0
        Y[i, j].upper = 1
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    Y = m.Array(m.Var, (N, k))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 1916, 
  in Array x = np.ndarray(dim,dtype=object)
TypeError: 'GKParameter' object cannot be interpreted
  as an integer
```

Comment: Please give a minimal but fully functioning example (including all imports) so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Gekko requires that the problem structure (equations) remain constant but variable values and bounds can change. If you don't want the last rows of variables then you can set up a static matrix and then turn on or off each row with `lower=upper=0`. When the lower and upper bounds are equal, the variable is fixed at that value and not used by the optimizer.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
k = 3
N = 6
Y = m.Array(m.Var, (N, k))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(k):
        Y[i, j].value = 0
        Y[i, j].lower = 0
        if i<N:
            Y[i, j].upper = 1
        else:
            Y[i, j].upper = 0
        m.Maximize(Y[i,j])
    m.solve(disp=False)
    print('Problem: ' + str(i))
    print(Y)
```

This produces 6 solutions where the value of `Y` is maximized.

```
Problem: 0
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
Problem: 1
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
Problem: 2
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
```

Each time through the loop, it is solving with one more row of variables.

```
Problem: 3
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
Problem: 4
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
Problem: 5
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]]
```